# How to modify a parse tree in ANTLR4?

Tags: antlr4

I have used ANTLR4 for writing a Fortran parse. Now I get the parse tree (there is no AST in ANTLR4). My next work is to modify the parse tree according to my needs, such as inserting new data declaration statements and replacing current statement. I looked for `addChild` in ANTLR java API documents, but it seems no such method in `RuleNode`. So what should I do?

Comment: I just found I should look for `ParserRuleContext`, which implements interface `ParseTree`. Where `RuleNode` is just a subinterface of `ParseTree`.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to embed your code in the grammar file. This makes things a lot messy.

Another way is to write your classes in a separate file, create the required objects in `@parser::members{...}` section or in action part of your rules, and use them to get details from the grammar. This way, you'll get information from the grammar and you can model your data with your classes.

Good Luck!